# Expression for the sigma function in terms of $d^2$.

Tags: number-theory

I am having trouble deciding on how to proceed with this problem:

Find an expression for $\Sigma_{d\mid n} d^2$ in terms of the prime decomposition $n=p_{1}^{\alpha_1}*p_{2}^{\alpha_2}*...*p_{t}^{\alpha_t}$ of n

Comment: it is number theoretic "multiplicative."

Comment: Welcome to math. SE.  What have you tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ be our function. Then $f$ is *multiplicative*. So if we can find an expression for any $f(p^\alpha)$, where $p$ is prime, then we can find an expression for $f(n)$ in terms of the prime power factorization of $n$. We have
$$f(p^\alpha)=1+p^2+p^4+\cdots +p^{2\alpha}.$$
This is a finite geometric series. The usual formula for the sum of such series gives
$$f(p^\alpha)=\frac{p^{2\alpha+2}-1}{p^2-1}.$$